# Los eventos del mouse no funcionan correctamente en Pygame y Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo esto:

```
while menu:
    #capturaEventos()
    global click
    global gameOver

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                gameOver = True
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                click = True
                print(click)
            else:
                click = False
                print(click)
    botonStart.imprimir()
    botonStart.interactuar()
    if botonStart.accion(0) and botonStart.interactuar():
        menu = False
        gameLoop()
```

El problema es que al pulsar el botón del mouse no reacciona correctamente al código, tardando demasiado en reaccionar y teniendo que pulsar varias veces hasta que se imprime `True`. No solo eso sino que no reacciona al evento `KEYDOWN` ni a `pygame.QUIT`. Para que todo funcione correctamente tengo que borrar estas líneas:

```
botonStart.imprimir()
botonStart.interactuar()
```

Estas líneas son un objeto de la clase `Boton` que contiene esto:

```
class Boton():
    def __init__(self, texto, color, x, y, ancho, altura):
        self.texto = texto
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ancho = ancho
        self.altura = altura
        self.xCenter = self.x + ancho / 2
        self.yCenter = self.y + altura / 2
        self.on_click = False


    #Cuando se llama a esta función, se imprime un botón.   
    def imprimir(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(pantalla, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.ancho, self.altura))

    #Cuando se llama a esta función, se interactua con el botón de forma que se enciende al pasar con el ratón. Retorna True si el ratón está sobre el botón 
    def interactuar(self):
        variacion = 75
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.x + self.ancho > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y + self.altura > mouse[1] > self.y:
            pygame.draw.rect(pantalla, (math.fabs(self.color[0]-variacion), math.fabs(self.color[1]-variacion),math.fabs(self.color[2]-variacion)), (self.x, self.y, self.ancho, self.altura))
            #print("estoy dentro del boton")
            return True
        else:   
            pygame.draw.rect(pantalla, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.ancho, self.altura))
            #print("estoy fuera del boton")
            return False
    def accion(self, boton):
        pass
```

Por qué está funcionando mal? Por qué ese lag que hace el código inservible? Podéis mostrarme la luz, por favor?

Comment: El código que muestras no está completo, por lo que no es posible tratar de reproducir tu problema. He intentado completarlo con el mínimo necesario para que funcione. El código final que estoy probando [es este](https://pastebin.com/Qhg7xW6Z). Resulta que me funciona perfectamente. No observo ese lag que tu dices, de donde deduzco que estará causado por otras partes del código que no muestras. Hay que decir que el `botonStart.imprimir()` sobraría pues el `interactuar()` ya lo pinta de todas formas.

Comment: He puesto solo el bucle que está implicado en el error. Lo curioso es que borrando ``botonStart.imprimir()`` y ``botonStart.interactuar()`` todo funciona correctamente por lo que parecía que el error ya estaba delimitado.

Comment: Lo he probado fuera y efectivamente funciona bien aislando el código. Este ``while`` está dentro de una función que a su vez está llamada desde la función principal. Puede ser ese el fallo? en todo caso, qué hay que hacer para que el ratón funcione sin tener que llamar a los eventos cada dos por tres? cuando estás en un bucle dentro de otra función no reconoce el evento ratón que está en la función principal. Yo vengo de Game Maker programando en GML y en cuanto creabas un evento mouse, servía para todo el juego. Y GML es bastante inferior que python sin posibilidad de programar en objetos.

Comment: Sin ver el código completo es difícil saber qué está ocurriendo, pero tiene pinta de que como consecuencia del bucle alguna función se está ejecutando muchas más veces de lo que debería. Fíjate si tu consumo de CPU se pone al 100% durante la ejecución de tu programa (con el mío no pasa del 15%). Por otro lado, parece que lo que necesitas es una biblioteca de más alto nivel que PyGame, que te proporcione _widgets_. Existen algunas que lo hacen usando PyGame por debajo mira [aqui](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui)